# Are very long shutdown times common when booting from NVMe?

Tags: linux, ssd, shutdown, ubuntu-18.04, nvme

As per subject I've just installed a Samsung 970 Evo and made it my bootable disk.

Start-up time is not much different from an SSD, shutdown time is taking 10+ minutes.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 with HWE (kernel 5+) and I have *not* done a fresh install, but cloned from my previous SSD.

When the computer is up, performance is great (can reach 2+ GiB write per second), but boot is slow and, crucially, shutdown takes 10+ minutes.

Any idea why?
Am I the only one experiencing this?

My motherboard is an Aorus z370 with latest firmware.

**Edit**

As requested, these are the last log lines before the shutdown (from `/var/log/kern.log`):

```
...
Aug 26 14:23:08 scv kernel: [   25.907858] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Aug 26 14:23:08 scv kernel: [   25.907867] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Aug 26 14:23:15 scv kernel: [   33.071042] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug 26 14:24:41 scv kernel: [  118.685677] rfkill: input handler enabled
```

The computer shutdown around 14:28 - I'll try executing the kernel with `debug` option to see if I get a more insightful log.

**Edit 2**

After setting the kernel in debug mode, I can shutdown and what happens is that the keyboard switches off (it's a LED Razer), but not the main PC.

Funny enough, when I restart the count of `Unsafe Shutdowns:` with `sudo smartctl -x /dev/nvme0n1` is the same as before, which implies that it's just the motherboard which doesn't power down.

I'm going to test by using the SSD again and see what happens.

**Edit 3**

After trying to use my SSD instead of the NVMe, I realized even the SSD was taking ages to shutdown.
I have reverted the bios, and after some bisecting, I've found out the best version is [F13](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/BIOS/mb_bios_z370-aorus-ultra-gaming_f13.zip), because [F14](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/BIOS/mb_bios_z370-aorus-ultra-gaming_f14_n.zip) has the issue, but previous versions such as [F11](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/BIOS/mb_bios_z370-aorus-ultra-gaming_f11.zip) are more unstable.

On a side note, my SSD broke after 30 minutes, I am sort of relieved I just moved the data to the NVMe.
Not sure if I should consider this lucky or not... :-)

Comment: If you do not use Bluetooth I would try to blacklist disable it, if this makes the shutdown faster. That seems to be unrelated to NVMe, though.

Comment: Indeed, but after all looked like it was a bios issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently was a [bios](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Motherboard/Z370-AORUS-Ultra-Gaming-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios) version issue. The version F14 (latest), has this regression.
F13 is actually working and shutdown is fast, I'm sticking with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hafe you tried reading your log files?

You can see the halt process of the computer in verbose, to see wich services take the longest to shutdown. This way you know where the problem is and where to look

to shutdown in verbose:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/6122/how-to-see-whats-going-on-during-shutdown

Or from terminal to see the boot log

sudo cat /var/log/boot.log (For boot log)
sudo cat /var/log/messages (for shuwdown log) If its in there.

**EDIT:**

Did you go from an SSD to an NVMe drive?
Because that are 2 different type of drives, S-ATA vs NVMe (PCI-e)
https://www.userbenchmark.com/Faq/What-s-the-difference-between-SATA-PCIe-and-NVMe/105

Comment: I've added some progress - I'll experiment now without the NVMe.

Comment: I've updated the original question with answer. found out the issue.